# How to get the language code based on country code in java

Tags: java, android, locale

How to get the language code based on country code in java 
 Hi
I had a situation where I need to find the language based on country code.

 For country name "switzerland" I had country code as "CH" . 
 But there can  be 3 languges like German,french and ukenglish in Switzerland . I need to find the language code based on country code.

Scenario : My country code is "CH" .  I need to get the language code based on this country code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `there can be 3 languges like German, French and` ... **Italian** (Suisse-Italian), not UK English! Well, they are all Switzerland variants of German, French and Italian.

Comment: So which of the three languages of Switzerland do you expect get? If not all three, it's not clear what you want. There's no "the" language code for Switzerland.

Comment: How to fetch the German language code for switzerland  country code  in java ?

Comment: If you already know you want German, rather than either of the other, equally official, languages, why not just use "de"? Or use `new Locale("ch", "de")` to create a Locale object for the combination of Switzerland and German.

Comment: iam also looking for answer. Have you got any solution for this

Answer (score 9):

This program prints the language codes for all available locales for Switzerland. It can easily be modified to e.g. return a `List<String>` of language codes. Picking the one you want is left as an exercise for the reader - the Swiss have not chosen to pick a single preferred language for their country.

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale[] all = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for (Locale locale : all) {
      String country = locale.getCountry();
      if(country.equalsIgnoreCase("CH")){
        System.out.println(locale.getLanguage());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
fr
de
it
```

Comment: BTW: if you need the country's name in a specific locale's language: https://www.mkyong.com/java/display-a-list-of-countries-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can use following constructor of [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) -

```
   Locale(String language, String country)
```

For USA (code: US) the language is English (code "en"). So you can do this -

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
```

Comment: Can I use like below :      Locale  locale = new Locale("CH");                     String language = locale.getDisplayLanguage(). is it correct ?

Comment: This answer is pretty unrelated to the question. @Android_programmer_office: no this is not correct. In fact, you cannot dereference a language from a country code directly. See Patricia's answer for further information.